# FileSystemManager getTime on FTP

Tags: date, time, ftp, vfs

I use the FileSystemManager (org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemManager) to get files from FTP/SFTP/Local/Shares Servers. 
What i need is the "now" time on the server where i get the File.

Is there any possibility to get the time via the FileSystemManager?
An alternative would also be the possibility to get the time "how long is this file on the server".

A workaround could be to create a new file and get the lastModifiedTime.. but I hope there is a smarter way.

Thanks